# Cartopy/Matplotlib RGBA error

Tags: matplotlib, cartopy

I am trying to plot a [shapefile](https://data.eindhoven.nl/explore/dataset/buurten/information/?dataChart=eyJxdWVyaWVzIjpbeyJjb25maWciOnsiZGF0YXNldCI6ImJ1dXJ0ZW4iLCJvcHRpb25zIjp7fX0sImNoYXJ0cyI6W3sidHlwZSI6ImNvbHVtbiIsImZ1bmMiOiJBVkciLCJ5QXhpcyI6ImJ1dXJ0Y29kZSIsInNjaWVudGlmaWNEaXNwbGF5Ijp0cnVlLCJjb2xvciI6IiM2NmMyYTUifV0sInhBeGlzIjoiYnV1cnRuYWFtIiwibWF4cG9pbnRzIjo1MCwic29ydCI6IiJ9XSwidGltZXNjYWxlIjoiIn0%3D) using custom colors on a map using cartopy and matplotlib.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy as cartopy
import pandas as pd
import random as rd

def getcolor(buurtnaam):
    a = rd.uniform(0.0, 255.0)
    b = rd.uniform(0.0, 255.0)
    c = rd.uniform(0.0, 255.0)
    return tuple([a, b, c, 1])

ax = plt.axes(projection=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_extent((5.35, 5.60, 51.4, 51.5), crs=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree())
filelocation=('buurt.shp')

reader = cartopy.io.shapereader.Reader(filelocation)

for label,shape in zip(reader.records(),reader.geometries()):
    coordinates=cartopy.feature.ShapelyFeature(shape, cartopy.crs.PlateCarree(),edgecolor='black')
    ax.add_feature(coordinates, facecolor=getcolor(label.attributes['buurtnaam']))
plt.show()
```

However, this yields the following result:

> ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: 5.850575504984446

When I check my RGBA values by printing them inside the for loop they appear to be correct.

```
print(label.attributes['buurtnaam'])
```

> Rochusbuurt

```
print (getcolor(label.attributes['buurtnaam']))
```

> (109.8833008320893, 179.51867989390442, 211.09771601504892, 1)

```
print (type(getcolor(label.attributes['buurtnaam'])))
```

> class 'tuple'

Is my RGBA formatting correct? Is this a bug in cartopy/matplotlib ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the mean time I solved it. A RGBA tuple should contain 4 values between 0 and 1.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy as cartopy
import pandas as pd
import random as rd

def getcolor(buurtnaam):
    a = rd.uniform(0.0, 1.0)
    b = rd.uniform(0.0, 1.0)
    c = rd.uniform(0.0, 1.0)
    return tuple([a, b, c, 1])

ax = plt.axes(projection=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_extent((5.35, 5.60, 51.4, 51.5), crs=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree())
filelocation=('buurt.shp')

reader = cartopy.io.shapereader.Reader(filelocation)

for label,shape in zip(reader.records(),reader.geometries()):
    coordinates=cartopy.feature.ShapelyFeature(shape, cartopy.crs.PlateCarree(),edgecolor='black')
    ax.add_feature(coordinates, facecolor=getcolor(label.attributes['buurtnaam']))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `get_color` function is generating random numbers which have nothing to do with your shapefile, and these numbers are being used for your RGB values.  When you pass the name of the attribute `buurtnaam` through to the function, you need to encorporate it in the RGB value generation somehow.

Comment: I did this in order to create a clear Mnimal Working Example. In practice I would replace this function with a function combining different properties into a color based on shape label.